# method call output is confusing

Tags: java

When the object reference b is instantiated in method main, the method getH() in class Beta is automatically executed. When the method getH() in class Beta is executed it's body, the println statement, is executed as well. However, when the method getH() is called using the reference variable b as a println statement argument in method main, the println statement thats included as part of the body of method getH() does not print. It seems to me that when the method getH() gets called in any case, its body (e.g. the println statement thats included as part of its body) should execute. But again, this doesn't appear to be whats occuring in this case. I'm trying to understand why (or whether my reasoning is incorrect)...

```
class Beta {
    public int h = 44;
    public int getH() {
        System.out.println(" test " + h);
        return h;
    }
    public static void main( String[] args) {
        Beta b = new Beta();
        System.out.println( b.getH());
    }
}
```

Comment: What output are you setting? I'm seeing " test 44" and then "44"... in other words, everything *is* printing.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is you're describing. From looking at the code it should print two lines, just like you say it should. Can you show us exactly the output you're receiving?

Comment: @vee, step through your program with a debugger. That should eliminate any misunderstanding about what is happening.

Comment: When I execute this code I receive two lines of output. The first line is test 44, the next line is 44. This suggests to me that the body of method getH() [e.g. the println stmt] is executed first - as a result of b being instantiated in method main; followed by the output 44, which the code suggests is being output by the println stmt in method main. My expectation is that whenever getH() is called the println stmt that is included as part of its body will execute.

Comment: Show us your output and what output you are expecting

Comment: It seems to me that when the method getH() gets called in any case, its body...should execute??
of course!!
as long as you have instance of Beta you will be able to call getH() and once you do that you will always have the println() method get called .. there is no condition that prevents it.

Comment: Try commenting out the System.out.println( b.getH()); line in your main method. When you do that you should get no output, which will show that getH is not called on instantiation.

Comment: @vee: Methods are only executed when they are explicitly invoked, they aren't executed just because you create a new instance of the class that defines the method.

Comment: "However, when the method getH() is called using the reference variable b as a println statement argument in method main, the println statement thats included as part of the body of method getH() does not print." That seems entirely incorrect to me.

Comment: @vee first you call a method, the method do it job and returns you something (if it has to) and then you will use that result to continue the next statement; you can not expect the println() in the main method to finish before the b.getH() finish executing .. the result print order is correct

Comment: @jdphenix's recommendation is the best of the bunch. Clarify in your mind what is happening by seeing for yourself how the code is executed and in what order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare the method it is not evaluated, you seem to expect the declaration to also execute it. Instead it executes when it is called.

```
public int h = 44;
public int getH() { // Declaration, not invocation.
    System.out.println(" test " + h);
    return h;
}
public static void main( String[] args) {
    Beta b = new Beta(); // Instantiation. Does not call getH.
    System.out.println( b.getH()); // <-- Now, getH is called on instance b.
}
```

Comment: Elliot. This is good. Understandable. Except that it doesn't quite explain the output that I get (e.g. "test 44" on one line, then "44" on the next).

Comment: When you call `getH()` it prints "test 44" on one line. Then it returns 44, and your `System.out.println` in `main()` then prints "44" on the next line.

Comment: @vee: as others have suggested -- walk through your code with a debugger. This way you can actually **see** when lines are executed and in what order.